# How do I verify an SSL certificate file (.crt) with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, ssl, google-cloud-platform

Basically I used to have a process that would load .csv files from a network shared drive in Windows to a cloud location (Google Cloud Storage). There were some changes in the network that I.T. implemented which disrupted this job, throwing an error that looks like this:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /storage/v1/b/bucket_cbsm?projection=noAcl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))`

I'm using Jupyter Notebooks / Python to write and test my script. Basically I.T. gave me a .crt file that they said was the SSL certificate and in the Google SDK shell I've confirmed I can point the gcloud command to that file and do a network diagnosis and it is successful. The thing is, I now have to somehow point my Python script to that .crt file location so that I can validate the SSL so that the rest of the script can run successfully. I know Python has an `ssl` library but just wondering if anyone has an idea on how to use it to validate a .crt SSL certificate that I have stored locally?

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import os

proj_id = 'test-project'
client = storage.Client(
                    #credentials=credentials,
                    project=proj_id #credentials.project_id
)

def uploadGCS(mybucket,myfile,filename,foldname):
    #mybucket = name of the GCS bucket
    #myfile = filepath for the specific CSV you want to upload to GCS
    #filename = name of the file that you uploaded (renames the uploaded file)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(mybucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(myfile)
    blob.upload_from_filename(myfile)
    bucket.rename_blob(blob, foldname+filename) #add "folderName/" before filename to indicate which folder to drop file in.

#intention below is to load the file for storage purposes (naming convention by date) into a GCS folder, and load the 
mybucket = 'bucket_cbsm'
foldname = 'daily ftp load/archives/'
loadfoldname = 'daily ftp load/current day/'
cadftp_path = csvoutput_path+'cadftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
usdftp_path = csvoutput_path+'usdftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'

fixedbase_path = csvoutput_path+'fixedbase_'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
prev_fixedbase_path =  csvoutput_path+'cadfixedprev_'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
aa_path =csvoutput_path+'aacurr_'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
csfs_path =csvoutput_path+'csfs_'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
genrates_path = csvoutput_path+'genrates_'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'

cadftp_load_path = csvoutput_path+'cadftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'
usdftp_load_path = csvoutput_path+'usdftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str+'.csv'

cadftp_name = 'cadftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str
usdftp_name = 'usdftpoutput'+curr_dtxl_str
cadftp_loadname = 'cadftpoutput'
usdftp_loadname = 'usdftpoutput'
fixedbase_name = 'fixedbase_'+curr_dtxl_str
prev_fixedbase_name =  'cadfixedprev_'+curr_dtxl_str
aa_name = 'aacurr_'+curr_dtxl_str
csfs_name = 'csfs_'+curr_dtxl_str
genrates_name = 'genrates_'+curr_dtxl_str



uploadGCS(mybucket,cadftp_path,cadftp_name,foldname) #uploads current day FTP file into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,usdftp_path,usdftp_name,foldname) #uploads current day FTP file into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,fixedbase_path,fixedbase_name,foldname) #uploads current day fixed base into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,prev_fixedbase_path,prev_fixedbase_name,foldname) #uploads previous day FTP file into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,aa_path,aa_name,foldname) #uploads current day FTP file into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,csfs_path,csfs_name,foldname) #uploads current day FTP file into archive storage
uploadGCS(mybucket,genrates_path,genrates_name,foldname) #uploads current day FTP file into archive storage

uploadGCS(mybucket,cadftp_path,cadftp_loadname,loadfoldname) #uploads current day FTP file into the loading folder for BQ 
uploadGCS(mybucket,usdftp_path,usdftp_loadname,loadfoldname) #uploads current day FTP file into the loading folder for BQ
```

Comment: There are several possible solutions to this problem. However, you have not shown the code or the certificate that is generating this error. The error is regarding a self signed certificate but Google does not use self signed certificates for public endpoints. Therefore your problem might be an out of date certificate bundle installed on your machine. More information is required to answer your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I've updated my post with the code snippet, but as you can see its not problem on Google's end I believe its just something I need to do in Python to validate the SSL certificate file that was provided to me. I've confirmed it works because in the Cloud Shell SDK the cert is successfully verified but just need to pass it in Python

Comment: Where are you using the certificate in the code that you added to your question? Improve  your question to match the error message with the line of code that generates the error.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm getting the error message from this piece of code. Its the reference to a network "S:Drive" that is causing the problem I believe, because I need to verify the SSL certificate that was provided to me via .txt/.crt. Just trying to figure out how to point my Python code to the .crt/.txt file

Comment: Then your problem has nothing to do with Google Cloud. Edit your question with details as asked. The type of certificate is important. In most cases a certificate used to validate a certificate goes into the certificate bundle and not your code. No details so I cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at it Sir.
https://rambling-ideas.salessandri.name/validating-a-ssl-certificate-in-python/